# Center bottom row cells inside table

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment

Yes, this is table-based layout. It's legacy so I may or may not be able to rip out the table, nonetheless I want to understand how table alignment works *anyway*, hence this arguably abhorrent question.

Say I have a 3x3 table with the values 1, 2, 3, ..., 8. It ends at 8, so the last row only has 2 elements in it. I want those centered.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td>6</td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td></tr>
</table>
```

I would like the CSS rule `tr { text-align: center }` to work, but I think there's some sort of table structure rule trumping what text align would do in this case, so some other style property maybe I have to cancel.

Fiddle, including a bunch of CSS that doesn't do what I want: http://jsfiddle.net/sdqtg7kr/

Answer (score 4):

If you want those bottom `td` elements to respect `text-align: center`, you could change the `display` of the elements from `table-cell` to `inline-block`.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/bgyyjxd4/)

```
td {
    border-color: red;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Sounds exactly right, I didn't realize there was a `table-cell` display.

Comment: @Ted He is probably aware that he can accept it. Besides, you have to wait 15mins after the question is asked. Thanks though :)

Comment: haha yeah, I just noticed he has 20k rep. I'm sure he's aware :p